# Labelling Curves Using ListLogLinearPlot within DynamicModule (So Close)

Tags: plotting, dynamic, legending, time-series, labeling

I currently have a large number of time-series datasets in the form where the name and time-series transposed data, so I have a list of lists of names for datasets and their time-dependant data.

The *end goal* is to graph a plot which **I already have as I want it by itself,** only with a **legend** that is, with other graphics, **finished as well.**  Within this expression for `myPlot` I am able to generate the labels I need via inserting an `Epilog` expression, producing

`SetAttributes[tt, Listable]
tt[name_ -> data_] := Tooltip[data, name]`  *(Just for manipulation)*

(1) `myPlot = ListLogLinearPlot[#, Epilog -> Table[Inset[Framed[DisplayForm[names[[i]]], RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> White], {5.5, 25}], {i, len}]]`

(2) `myPlot /@ tt[thirds@ruleData] // Column`

which together yield a plot with unmovable labels for each dataset ((2) actually yields the plots with or without Epilog / labels, as specified by (1), whereas (1) alone unsquelched yields itself back in text-only output).

But I am unable to combine these expressions with `DynamicModule` as another post on the Stack Forums suggests.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221315/how-do-i-label-different-curves-in-mathematica

However, on top of a dummy graphic (table "pos" rather than plot) **I can get `DynamicModule` to have movable labels:**

`DynamicModule[{pos = Table[{names[[i]]}, {i, len}]}, LocatorPane[Dynamic[pos], Appearance -> Table[Framed[Text@TraditionalForm[names[[i]]], RoundingRadius -> 5,Background -> White], {i, len}]]]`

So, I would think the only problem then is figuring out how to "insert" the `myPlot` function(s) into `DynamicModule`.

I am almost certain the presence of the `#` in my `ListLogLinearPlot` function is the culprit.  I need to combine these expressions labels are movable ON the graph just as they are on the dummy table.

Thank you again, I deeply appreciate any resposnes.

Comment: Je n’ai fait celle-ci plus longue que parce que je n’ai pas eu le loisir de la faire plus courte.

Comment: @belisarius Sorry, I will edit it to make it shorter... I just didn't want to leave anyone without a detail they needed.  I'll try to omit excesses.

Comment: Please consider it an opinion an not a dogmatic truth

Answer (score 3):

Here's a guess at what you're after:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-0.2, 0.2}, 300]];
thirds = Partition[data, 100];
interps = Interpolation /@ thirds;
myplot = ListLogLinearPlot[thirds];

DynamicModule[{pos = MapThread[{Log@#, #2[#]} &, {{5, 16, 50}, interps}]}, 
 LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[pos,
    (pos = MapThread[
       Function[{pt, interp}, {#, interp@Exp@#} &@ Clip[First@pt, Log@interp["Domain"][[1]]]],
       {#, interps}]) &],
  Show[myplot,
    Graphics[{Dynamic @ Table[Inset[
                 Framed[Text@TraditionalForm[i], RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> White],
                 pos[[i]]], {i, 3}]}]],
  Appearance -> None
  ]
 ]
```

[image: List plot with movable labels]

Notes;

1. `pos` should be a list of points, not `myplot`.
2. The plot should be the back of `LocatorPane`.
3. The second argument of `Dynamic` constrains the `Locators` to follow the plot; the interpolations `interps` are used to determine the y-coordinates.
4. The `Locators` are given no `Appearance`, but they're still there and are used to place the labels.
5. Elements of the back that change should be wrapped inside a `Dynamic`.

Comment: Thank you.  I've entered that verbatim in Mathematica and like that the labels are not only movable by mouse, they are bound to their respective functions.  I'll see if I can integrate this with my notebook! @Michael

Comment: That is, on the data you've given I mean.  I still need to work it into the notebook... now to figure out how to use `thirds` in `ListLogLinearPlot` given 

`thirds[lst_List] := Partition[lst, #, #, 1, {}] &@Ceiling[Length@lst/3]`

or a functional equivalent.  Sorry, I'm very new, I'll be back when I've progressed. @Michael